# Can I use Apple's Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) to Thunderbolt 2 Adapter for Target Display Mode on an iMac?

Tags: imac, thunderbolt, displayport, thunderbolt-display

Apple's support page for the [Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) to Thunderbolt 2 Adapter](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592) lists support for Thunderbolt Displays and no support for Apple DisplayPort displays. However it doesn't say anything about iMacs with Thunderbolt in Target Mode mode. Does Apple's Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) to Thunderbolt 2 Adapter support Target Display Mode on an iMac?

My guess is that it does since Apple's support page for Target Display Mode says that you have to use a Thunderbolt source for an iMac with Thunderbolt in order to use Target Display Mode.

Comment: I am also wondering this. Any updates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I'm successfully running a setup with a 2017 13" MacBook Pro and a 2011 iMac. The original Apple USB-C to Thunderbolt 2 Adapter works fine for Target Display Mode.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no.

I am running a setup with a 2016 MacBook Pro, the Thunderbolt 3 to Thunderbolt 2 adapter and a 2013 iMac 27".

**Edit: I was wrong. It is possible. You will have to press Cmd+F2 to active TDM with this configuration. My old iMac switches to TDM automatically. That's why I was confused, sorry!**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in some circumstances. This [Apple support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592) lists the supported hardware combinations and required cable(s).

Comment: Hi Nathan, and welcome to Ask Different! On this site, we are looking for answers that include details, and not just links. Could you elaborate some more on your answer, including some details about what is found at the link? Learn more about writing great answers in the [help center](/help/how-to-answer). Thanks, and happy answering!