# Target Display Mode not working on MacBook Pro 13" 2020

Tags: macbook-pro, imac, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

I am using a 2011 iMac as an external monitor (and speakers) for my MacBook Pro (2014) on a daily basis.

Last week, I upgraded to the 2020 MBP 13". The new MBPs with USB-C are [supposed to work](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/293950/378127) with Target Display Mode, using the Thunderbolt 2 to USB-C adapter. I have it connected with an official Apple Thunderbolt 2 cable and Thunderbolt 2 to USB-C adapter. But when I press Command-F2, nothing happens, like they aren't connected.

I can already rule out the cable/adapter/USB-C port being defective, because I've used for transferring files from the old MacBook to the new one successfully. It also still works fine when I connect the Thunderbolt cable (directly) to my old MBP.

Any ideas what I can do to debug the problem?

**Edit:** I tried it out with a colleague's MBP 2017, same cable and adapter, and it worked flawlessly. So the problem seems to be limited to the new 2020 MBP. I am in direct contact with a very helpful (and seemingly persistent) 2nd line Apple Support employee about this now, so fingers crossed.

Comment: What version of macOS is on the target iMac? And you’re pressing command on the iMac keyboard?

Comment: @bmike The MacBook Pro is on Catalina (10.15.5), and the iMac is running High Sierra.

Comment: Hmm - High Sierra should be supported, but the [iMac hardware is vintage so that makes official support hard to expect at this point](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201624). Would be nice if it kept working, but there's no expectation of support I have at this point for this. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592

Comment: Yep, I understand, although the problem seems to be with the 2020 MBP rather than the iMac. All other machines are connecting just fine. I don't want to sound entitled but I really do expect this to work, and if not to be fixed. I invested a lot in all these Apple devices (now again €100 in cables and adapters), I expect them to work (and keep working) together, at least where technically possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Target Display Mode has been retired and won't be coming back, it seems the new [AirPlay to Mac](https://www.apple.com/macos/monterey-preview/features/) functionality in macOS Monterey is the spiritual successor and like for like replacement for it!

> Use AirPlay to send content to your Mac from an iPhone, iPad, **or
> even another Mac**. View videos, edit Keynote presentations, and hear
> music on your Mac as it’s being played from your other device.
>
> **AirPlay works both wirelessly and wired using USB.** A wired connection
> is useful when you want to ensure that there’s no latency or you don’t
> have access to Wi-Fi.

It should work with a MacBook Pro (2018 and later), MacBook Air (2018 and later), and iMac (2019 and later) or iMac Pro (2017).

I am excited to try this out. If the iMac delivers enough power you can probably go with just one USB-c cable to your MacBook, similar to some of the current USB-c displays.

Answer (score 6):

Same issue here!

New 2020 MBP, using an apple USB-C to thunderbolt adapter, apple thunderbolt cable, mid 2011 iMac.

Apple support just informed me that they don't have this feature in newer devices. What a shame!

I'm filling out a feedback form suggesting that they bring it back. Perhaps naively hopeful that they'll respond but worth a shot.

Comment: I really hope this is not the case — Apple refusing to support using two of *their* products together would be quite unacceptable to me. If it's the case that it's just a matter of will, we should make some noise ;)

Comment: The apple support person said they are also disappointed. I don't know why they got rid of it, but I send in a feedback form here https://www.apple.com/feedback/macbookpro.html

Comment: Same issue with the 2020 macbook pro connecting to a 27" 2012 iMac. It was working flawlessly with the 2015 version macbook pro. 55 EUR for an adapter that doesn't work at all. I want to believe this is only a SW issue that will be fixed, I am really getting fed up with Apple lately.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem. I spent about an hour with Apple's support team providing information. They are working on the problem, with one possibility being an issue in the latest Catalina update. I am running 10.15.4 on both my MacBook Pro (which is working) and on my wife's MBA (which isn't working). I updated the MBA to the latest Catalina version before trying Target Display Mode, so I don't know if it would have worked prior to the latest Catalina update.

Comment: It's still not working with the new MacBook M1 Pro/Max ... probably due to Thunderbolt 4 not properly implemented this fallback Thunderbolt 2 feature or something ...